# Why was the question about Aaron's rod sprouting closed off without being answered properly?

Tags: discussion

When I saw [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/5517/43) earlier today I was new to the site and didn't see why no one answered it.  Found one answer here -- http://bibleq.net/answer/1998/

Answer (score 2):

Notice that [GoneQuiet posted a comment a day after the question was posted](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5517/aarons-sprouted-rod#comment11480_5517) (technically only a few hours later), where she said:

> Welcome to BH. Could you identify (and perhaps quote) the passage in
>   Numbers (I assume) that you're referring to? Also, I haven't heard the
>   idea before that his staff might be a live tree (what you seem to be
>   suggesting); if you know where you got that idea, adding it would be
>   helpful. Thanks, and I look forward to seeing you around the site.
>   (You can edit by using the "edit" link under your question.)

The question was posted on July 31, 2013, and the comment on August 1, 2013. The question was not closed until August 18, 2013. The OP had quite a bit of time to address the concerns of the community but chose not to do so. Also, the question demonstrated poor grammar and spelling, contained a signature ([which is against site guidelines](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)), and made assertions with no source for the information. It was unclear specifically what the user was asking for, which is reflected in the close reason. [We are not a forum nor a conventional Q&A site.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/about)